# Can we add payable modifier to transfer function while implementing ERC721 token?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Could we add payble modifier to transfer function while implementing erc721 smart contract.I have made a non-fungible digital asset and wants to add logic to but that asset.

Comment: A note for everybody else -- the `payable` keyword is specified in the ERC-721 standard, therefore it is *optional* for everyone to use it. This is because all non-payable functions meet the requirement as a payable function.

Answer (score 2):

The final version of the ERC-721 https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md expects `payable` keyword on functions `safeTransferFrom`, `transferFrom` and `approve`.

Comment: I'd recommend you check the complete reference implementation of the ERC-721 non-fungible token standard for the Ethereum blockchain https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721 for details. You can also use https://erc721validator.org to check if your smart contract is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Current ERC721 does not have function called `transfer`. I suspect you might be looking at older version of ERC721 standard, so if you really want to make your contract compliant, make sure you are implementing the right interface.

Current version of ERC721 proposal can be found here https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md. Note that it is not yet finalized, though very close to be.

And as a matter of fact, as you can see in the current ER721 proposal, the transfer functions are all payable. The reason for that was [explained here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42466/why-are-the-transfer-and-approve-functions-payable-in-the-erc-721-spec)